# Uses of the phrasal-verb "settle down"

Tags: phrasal-verbs

Can I use the phrasal-verb "settle down" in the following contexts:

**"I have to settle down what I learned"** - to study more deeply, to review subjects that were previous learned

**"If the computer won't settle down call us again"** - recover from an issue, to work normaly again

**"With this medication the symptoms will settle down"** - to decrease the intensity, recover from a disease

Thanks

Comment: settle down implies there has been some sort of agitation or commotion. Ergo,"settle down what I have learned" does not work. "Now that I have settled down after a fight with my brother, I can get down to studying again".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One could let what one had learn "settle" but that would not mean more studying but giving yourself a break to let you absorb what you had already studied.  To [settle down](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/settle%20down) to studying means to stop whatever was preventing you and get to work.

> to become quiet and **begin** giving one's attention to something

Emphasis mine.

You might use it for the computer in the sense

> to become quiet, calm, or orderly

but only if the computer had been acting in a bizarre and random manner.

As for the symptoms, that would be unusual.  One would refer to the body or organ as settling down if it could be described as acting up before.  One would not say that one's headache or head had settled down, but if you suffer from an upset stomach, a treatment might make the stomach settle down.

Comment: Symptoms can conceivably include some form of agitation. If you have the shakes (mental or physical).